# Does it matter if I execute a stored procedure with the prefix dbo or not?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was advised when executing a stored procedure, I should include the prefox dbo e.g.

exec dbo.'name_of_stored_procedure'

- Does it matter if I don't include the prefix?
- When should I use the prefix?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted on your other question? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your stored procedure is in the `dbo` schema, then you should say:

```
EXEC dbo.name_of_procedure;
```

Pros for specifying schema:

- you know you're calling dbo.procedure even if there is also some_other_schema.procedure
- the query engine doesn't have to go check your default schema for a similarly named object first
- you don't get unpredictable results (e.g. if there is one in your schema but you *meant* `dbo`)
- you have a better chance at query plan re-use if everyone consistently uses schema

Cons for specifying schema:

- you type an extra four characters

What else does *not* being explicit buy you?

Comment: And if you dragged the object over from the object browser, you don't even have to type the schema, it gives it to you automatically. So even less reason not to use it.

Comment: @HLGEM I get the same argument about `SELECT *` : "But it's so much work to type the columns!" Yes, it is. Now go expand the table in Object Explorer and drag the Columns node onto the query window. "Ooh! Magic!"

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I assume that it if the database is given `dbo` permissions, the stored procedures below it inherit the schema. Is thar right? The reason being is that when I created the stored procedure i.e. `CREATE PROCEDURE Name_of_Procedure`, I did not specify the prefix `dbo`

Comment: No, I am not sure how you give a database dbo permissions? Anyway if you say `CREATE PROCEDURE x` it will be created in whatever schema is *your user's* default schema. In some cases that is dbo, in some cases it is not. Why do you still seem to want to continue creating procedures without specifying the schema? If you want it to live in dbo, and you expect it to live in dbo, why not just specify dbo explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, it's best to be explicit and include the default schema [dbo] whenever you refer to objects, because later you may wish to define your own schemas which have stored procs or tables with the same name.
e.g.

```
dbo.sp_GetNames
Cities.sp_GetNames
Countries.sp_GetNames
```

Comment: When you say 'schemas' what do you mean?

Comment: You can create your own schemas to allow you to better logically group your objects. E.g you may have one schema for internal business data, and another for external, and different schemas can be assigned different permissions with different database users

Comment: Here's a good link explaining schema separation in SQL Server 2008:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Awesome NPix. It is great to understand what a schema is now. I am assuming it would be referred to as a security schema.

Answer (score 2):

dbo is not a prefix, is the schema
Schema are like groups, you can create a schema called Production and have your procedures like Production.AddStock and another called Sales and have procs like Sales.GetCustomer

They are specially good to manage permissions.
This link may help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Comment: I think your definition of the word "prefix" may differ from mine. Where I come from, that's a prefix, and I've never heard anyone suggest otherwise. If you were to call it what it is in structure (not in real terms, e.g. schema), what would you call it? Considering that it is an optional part of the 2-, 3- or 4-part name? Also I don't think you've answered the question. You've explained what schemas are and what they are for, but not why they should be used when calling a procedure.

Comment: @Diego - Thanks for the explanation on schemas. As a newbie, it is good to get an idea of the terminology as well as its meaning.